# How am I supposed to make my For-loop work? Brand new to For-loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-studio-2013

```
for (int h = 5; h >= 1; --h)
{
    for (int ah = 1; ah <= 5; ++ah)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

_getch();
```

I need this For loop to display five stars, then on the next line four stars, then on the next three stars, then two stars, and then one star. But for the life of me, I cannot figure it out. I am brand new to For loops. What do I need to change? This is all the code I am allowed. I can only change what is inside the () next to the for's.

Comment: Welp, it looks like you need to make your inner `for` loop dependent on the counter from the outer `for` loop. Something like `ah <= h` should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

When a problem is too complicated, break it into pieces.

One thing you want to do is "write out some number of stars". e.g. you can write a function

```
void write_stars_and_newline(int n)
{
    for (int ah = 1; ah <= n; ++ah)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

and then to draw your triangle

```
for (int h = 5; h >= 1; --h)
{
    write_stars_and_newline(h);
}
```

Now, since you're required to keep the nested `for` loop structure, you can *inline* this solution: you can replace the call to `write_stars_and_newline` with its contents, making sure to replace the parameter `n` with the value you passed into it (`h`):

```
for (int h = 5; h >= 1; --h)
{
    for (int ah = 1; ah <= h; ++ah)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Generally speaking, if you have already written the first solution, you usually shouldn't do that last step unless you believe it makes the code easier to read and understand. But we have to make allowances to carry out your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at both of the loops:

```
for (int h = 5; h >= 1; --h)
    for (int ah = 1; ah <= 5; ++ah)
```

In both of them, you are iterating **5** times, what gives you 5 * 5 = 25 stars. You want 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15 stars. To do that, you only need to change one part of only of one of these loops. What would it be?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  It will make the number of times the inner for loop change based on the value in the outer for loop.

```
for (int h = 5; h >= 1; --h)
{
    for (int ah = 1; ah <= h; ++ah)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

_getch();
```